# how to pass an expression as a parameter?

Tags: bash

**Problem:**

In a general way, I'm seeking a replicable way to do such things :

```
command expression_to_be_valuated
```

where `expression_to_be_valuated` would be any expression, which once executed would give, for example a number, so I would have

```
command parameter
```

where parameter is a number.

**Current situation**

I have the following expression

```
kill ps aux | grep '[m]ono ./' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Where if you refer to my explanation from above `command` is `kill` and `expression_to_be_valuated` is `ps aux | grep '[m]ono ./' | awk '{print $2}'`

I want this part to be evaluated before:

```
ps aux | grep '[m]ono ./' | awk '{print $2}'
```

However I tried to have `''` around it (which to my understanding up to now meant "evaluate this expression before", normally it works but in this case I'm not able to make it works, or to call an eval on it, but it doesn't work.

**Tries:**

```
ps 'aux | grep '[m]ono ./' | awk '{print $2}''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) and say `ps $( command )`:

```
ps $(aux | grep '[m]ono ./' | awk '{print $2}')
```

The `$(command)` expression evaluates `command`, so that if you say `ps $(command)`, `ps` gets the output of `command` as input.

Note also that `grep '[m]ono ./' | awk '{print $2}'` can be squeezed into just `awk '/mono .\// {print $2}'`.

---

From the given link:

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the
>   command itself.

Comment: thanks a lot!! So this is $() which means evaluate this thing before!! I will mark it as answer as soon as I could. However to correct my problem what I did was kill $(ps aux | grep '[m]ono ./' | awk '{print $2}')

Comment: `aux` is part of the `ps` call not the start of the piped command to `grep`. Also don't use `ps | grep` use `pgrep`.

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim glad to see it worked to you! Also, take into account what Etan is commenting --interesting and useful.